# Electron Menubar Icon Size

Tags: macos, timer, icons, electron, menubar

I'm working on a desktop time management application using electron. And I'd like to put a counting down timer on the menu bar. But right now the icon size needs to be 20*20. Is it possible to change the icon size in electron?

Comment: I have exactly the same question.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that the size of the image defines the size of the icon in the bar.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in this Github [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6121) you can use nativeImage command:

```js
const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage

...

{
    label: 'Open-Source',
    icon: nativeImage.createFromPath(__dirname + '/resources/icons/github.png').resize({width:16}),
    click: async () => {
        //
    }
}
```

You can create images with numbers then make a logic to set icons after X seconds and also use the nativeImage function to resize it with your mentioned size.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not work as nativeImage is not defined and is not exported from electron.

Comment: @Tomato yes, it is. take a look in the documentation here [link](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/native-image). You need to: `const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage`

Comment: Thank you @DanielMaceira, I have already figured it out by now.

Comment: Great @Tomato! Help me upvoting my answer :)